# try_files, alias, and regexp locations

Tags: nginx

I have a regexp location for a subdirectory (`/foo`) and want Nginx to do this for a request to `/foo/bar`:

1. Check if `bar` is a file or directory in the root defined in the location. If it is a directory, check for the index file.
2. If there is no file or directory `bar` fallback to the given URI (there is another working handler for .php files).

It looks like this:

```
location ~ ^/foo(/.*)?$ {
  root /my/root/with/files;
  index index.php;
  try_files $1 $1/ /my/root/with/files/index.php?$args;
}
```

Should be simple, but I can't get this working, and the documentation does not help. I tried many combinations of `alias`, `root` and whatever.

Any suggestions, how to get this working? Or do you know where to get useful documentation about try_files, root, alias, locations (including notes about outstanding bugs)?

Comment: I would recommend moving your `root` and `index` directives outside of the location as suggested in [nginx pitfalls](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls).

Comment: Generaly yes, but this root and index belong (in my case) to this specific location (or application on this host). I first put them to a nested location, but as said, nested locations and Nginx are considered evil ;)

Answer (score 1):

I got rid of most of my regexp and nested locations (seem to be buggy, especially in combination with the `alias` and `try_files` directive), and now it works like this:

```
location /foo/ {
    alias /my/root/with/files/;
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /foo//foo/index.php?$args;
}
```

The last argument to `try_files` seems odd, but the `alias` directive in combination with the location will replace the first `/foo/`.

Lesson learned: Keep things as simple as possible (forget about elegance in your configuration ;) ) in Nginx or it will blow your mind.